# Handling text elements of web pages using qml keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, qt, webkit, qml

I am using the Qt Web Kit 1.0 to open web pages. I have a keyboard available with me, written in qml. I want to use this keyboard to fill in the text into text boxes of the HTML pages.

Say, I opened gmail.com. Now, I want to fill in the user name and password. But when I will click on this text element of the webpage, what event should I handle to bring out my keyboard for user to use it ? And where exactly will I send this text generated from the keyboard, for it to be set into the username field of that page ?

Comment: I think you need to provide some more details. Are you using the QML WebView Element? (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-webview.html)  Or are you doing the web kit stuff in C++?

Comment: I have used nothing but Qml to make my browser. Yes, Qml WebView element and other such Qml entities. I am not able to get what event would be generated when I will click in the above described fields on a web page, opened using WebView element.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text field value by evaluating some custom javascript code in the `WebView`:

```
webViewId.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('textInputId').value = '" + yourValueString + "'")
```

Documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-webview.html#evaluateJavaScript-method).

*Edit:*
For the keyboard activation you can refer to the [javaScriptWindowObjects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-webview.html#javaScriptWindowObjects-prop) property: you can activate it, for example,  in the body `onload` event, or in the text field `onfocus` event.

*Edit2:*
I add a simple example to explain what I'm trying to say:

I assume you have a QML custom Item called `Keyboard`, and that this Item has a signal `onKeyPress` called whenever a key is pressed.

Your code should be something like this:

```
WebView {
    id: webViewId
    javaScriptWindowObjects: QtObject {
        WebView.windowObjectName: "qml"

        function showKeyboard {
            keyboardId.opacity = 1;
        }
    }

    onLoadFinished: {
        evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('textInputId').onfocus = window.qml.showKeyboard;")
    }
}

Keyboard {
    id: keyboardId
    opacity: 0

    onKeyPress: {
        webViewId.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('textInputId').value += '" + keyValue + "'")
    }
}
```

Comment: **' _you can activate it, for example, in the body onload event, or in the text field onfocus event_'**  I should bring out the keyboard normally when user clicks on a text input box [INSIDE THE WEB PAGE]. When I will click in username field for example, PAGE will generate some signal/event. How am I supposed to catch that event and then bind it to an action in qml ?

Comment: Similarly for your other response about setting the text field, where and how exactly can I specify that assign this text (say "my_user_name") i just entered through the keyboard, to the 'userName' text input box field of the site (say gmail.com ) ?

Comment: 1) QML keyboard --> page JS: You can catch a key press event in your QML keyboard, and use `evaluateJavaScript` to execute a JS script that will add the pressed key value to the text field.

2) page JS events --> QML keyboard show up: In the documentation I've linked about `javaScriptWindowObjects` there is a simple example on how to use it for executing some QML function within the web page JS. You can manipulate any page you've loaded and add a call to a function that will show the QML keyboard.